# Pausing Calendar notifications during presentations

Tags: macos, calendar, notifications

While giving a talk (PDF file rendered by Preview) from my MacBook, I'd like to make sure that my upcoming appointments do not show up during the talk.

Is it possible to pause these notifications? How?

Using another account on my machine is not an option. I need to be able to give live code demos from my main account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable **Do Not Disturb** from the top of Notification Center. Open Notification Center using the button on the menu bar or swiping in from the right side of the trackpad with two fingers, then scroll up and turn the switch on.

[image]

You can also ⌥-click on the Notification Center menu bar item to quickly toggle Do Not Disturb. The icon will turn grey to indicate the change in state.

Comment: The "scroll up" part is the mystery then. Despite formidable UI design, so many elements in OSX remain a secret until one needs them and asks.

Comment: For something that's not needed often for most people I think the discovery is OK here. If you go to System Preferences > Notification Center it tells you right there how to turn on DND by scrolling down.